# MKMapView overlays at fixed indexes

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I've a mix of `MKCircle`, `MKPolygon` and `MKPolyline` overlays which I want to appear in a specific order. These overlays are not always created at the same time but when they get created they shall appear below/above other overlays.

```
[self.mapview insertOverlay:example1 atIndex:6];
```

puts the overlay at the end of the list but not a layer 6 if there only is 2 overlays at the moment it seems to get number 3. I want to push the overlay at it's correct layer

```
[self.mapview insertOverlay:example2 atIndex:5];
```

this one I want to be above example1 but since that one got 3, example2 are now at the bottom.

I'm thinking of check which overlays are created and then create an array and push all of them with `addOverlays`, not sure how much of a performance hit it will give.

Are they any clever ways how this could be accomplished?

cheers, tord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need more structured management of annotations or overlays, you want to consider introducing a separate set of data structures to represent your organizational model (similarly to how one would manage a UITableView data source). A helper object or subclass of MKMapView can work; I prefer the former.

In your case, perhaps an array of arrays would work. The top level array represents each logical "layer". Each element in this array is an array of the overlays at that layer. These data structures should be owned, as private members, of your helper class, along with a weak reference or outlet to the MKMapView object. Provide methods to add/remove overlays, e.g. `addOverlay:atLayer:` and `removeOverlay:`, or pluralized variants that accept arrays of overlays. The helper class would first add the given overlays to the appropriate "layer" sub-array. Then, by adding up the counts of the arrays at the other layers, it can calculate the correct index value to use in the `insertOverlay:atIndex:` message you send to the MKMapView.

I don't think there will be any significant hit on performance or memory usage.

By having a separate helper class instead of a subclass of MKMapView or embedding the code inside your view controller, it can be easier to reuse this in multiple view controllers, and it can also be easier to unit test.